# The similarity between Mallows Cp and AIC?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, likelihood, aic, information-criteria

It is possible to compute the log-likelihood used for AIC as $n /log(RSS/n) + const$ or even as $RSS/\sigma^2 + n\log(\sigma) + const$ considering the least-square or MLE scenario for linear and non-linear models with a Gaussian error distribution.

It is often stated that Mallows Cp is almost the same as AIC in this scenario. Nevertheless, the term $RSS_i/\sigma^2$ in Mallows Cp is usually computed, estimating $\sigma$ using the model with most parameters. So, this sigma is fix and the $RSS_i$ changes for every tested model.

Now as far as I know, AIC usually uses the MLE estimate of $\sigma_i=RSS_i/n$ in the described scenario for every individual model and plugs it into the equation to compute the likelihood.

These are two very different ways of computing the term related to the $RSS$. Why are they still called almost the same and is this different approach intended?